# Smarty remove everything after last character

Tags: php, html, url, smarty

I have a Smarty variable thats called`{$url}` and it contains following URL:

```
$url = https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world:itsme
```

I want everything after the last ":" to be removed.

The result **should** look like this:

```
$result = https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world
```

With my knowledge it was only possible for me that I get the following result:

```
$result = https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello
```

How can I get this result with Smarty?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with **explode,array_slice and implode**
Like this :-

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world:itsme';
$array=explode(':',$url);
$array=array_slice($array, 0, 3);
$url=implode(':',$array);
https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world //as o/p
```

**Modified**:-
For removing everything after the last ":" use **array_pop**
Like this

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world:itsme:itsme2';
$array=explode(':',$url);
array_pop($array);
$url=implode(':',$array);
https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world:itsme //as o/p
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but I also have URL's with more than 2 ":" and this solution just always "cuts them off" after the 2nd one. Do you have any other solution for me in this case? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay now try with the modified answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

i trested it and work :

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello:world:itsme";
$i=7;
while($url[$i]!=':') $i++;
echo (substr($url,0,$i));
?>
```

Comment: Hello, it looks like this solution does not work. I also tried it in PHPFiddle, but it looks like URL always is https://www.example.com/?parameter=hello. Thanks for your help!